# Location services works differently on two iphones

Tags: iphone, objective-c, location

So I have this problem - I have a super simple app that all it does it to track your location with an On/Off button on the UI. I am testing on both iPhone 3GS (version 4.3) and iPhone 4 (version 5.0 beta), and suddenly on the 3GS, when I click on Off, it doesnt stop - I still see the location symbol on the status bar.

Previously, it worked fine on the 3GS - I could start, stop, send to background, launch again. etc. and my OFF button worked perfectly - whenever I stopped location, the location indicator disappeared. The SAME code runs on my iPhone4 and no issues.

My question is - is there a way to "clean" a test iphone? Wondering maybe there are some "cookies" kinda of stuff left that I should be cleaning so it will work again...otherwise, I am clueless...

thank!

Comment: And they're both running the latest version (4.3.3)? The icon may continue to appear, but the app is no longer tracking your location. It'll disappear when the app is closed.

Comment: No, the iPhone 4 runs the iOS 5 beta. And no, on the 3GS the location indicator is ALWAYS ON, even if I close the app, and restart the iphone - it comes back up with the location indicator on. The only way to make it go away is either: turn off location services, or delete the app :) BTW - I do have it setup to run in the background, but still - how can it be running after a restart....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LocationServices will continue to get updates even when the App is in the background on OS 4+, unless you stop updates when the application goes into the background. See the various -stop... [methods on CLLocationManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html). I can't be of much more help without a bit of the code you're using to start monitoring location, since there are so many different options for location monitoring.

Comment: I am using this (sorry cant post code in other way): - (IBAction)startUpdating 
{
    [CLController.locMgr startUpdatingLocation];        
}


- (IBAction)stopUpdating
{
    [CLController.locMgr stopUpdatingLocation];    
}
where the different IBAction represent two UI buttons that the use click to start / stop location. Previously on my 3GS (and still on my iphone 4), when pressing "Stop", the location indicator disappeared completely, whether on background or foreground....

Comment: If you want the phone to stop monitoring location changes when it enters the background, you need to track if your application is monitoring location updates. Then, in your app delegate -applicationWillResignActive and -applicationDidEnterBackground methods, send stopUpdatingLocation to your CLController.locMgr instance.

Comment: It's the same app, so the problem should be common to both devices. Except if iOS 5 is smarter and doesn't allow apps to be stupid and leave the service on. But I doubt that. ;-)

Comment: The more I re-read the original post, the more confused I get what device is exhibiting what behavior. @TommyG, can you edit your post to clarify what OS each device has on it, and what the behavior of that device is vs. what you expect?

Comment: @Randy Marsh iOS 5 is many things, consistent isn't yet one of them.

Comment: @RyanR: Maybe that's the reason. Maybe there's a bug so that the wanted behavior (the stopping of Location Services) is actually a bug and that TommyG's app has an error. (Edit: I'm sorry if you realized all this before me, and I'm explaining the obvious. :-p)

Comment: Made some edits - hope this is better now. BTW - I implemented my location services from a tutorial that i saw online (http://www.vellios.com/2010/08/16/core-location-gps-tutorial/) - this guy is using CoreLocationController, which I am not sure why - I watched the WWDC 2010 location workshop, and they dont say anything about this object. Maybe thats what is messing up my app?

Comment: One more piece of information - both on my simulator AND my 3GS - when I click on STOP, I stop receiving location updates, and when clicking on START - I am getting the updates. From some reason the simulator doesnt have the location services symbol, so hard to compare the behavior on the simulator versus my phones.

Comment: @TommyG you should try core location without that other controller, so you can be familiar with how it works, before you add another layer of abstraction. CLLocationManager is really quite simple to use, the apple docs for it are quite good.

Comment: So I dont need CoreLocationController? Do I need a new class like he is doing in this tutorial?

Comment: CoreLocationController is not a part of the SDK, I don't know what it does. You need to setup and use the CLLocationManager to get location information from the device. I encourage you to build a bare bones application using just classes from the SDK so you are familiar with what Core Location can and cannot do, and how to use it properly. Once you're comfortable with it, _then_ add in other bits to manage it for you (such as this CoreLocationController).

Comment: My bad...CoreLocationController was the name of a class created by the person I downloaded this code from (a blog teaching how to use this API). I figured it out now - I created a new class for the "API engine" and my view controller is instantiates it and uses it. What's weird (and unrelated) is that when I switch to iOS 5.0 simulator, I get a bunch of errors....ohh well.

Comment: @TommyG, remember iOS 5 is only at beta 2, so getting errors from it is not weird at all :)

Comment: @TommyG, Not naive. I'll answer your question with a real example. One of my apps is going to benefit quite a bit from iOS 5, so I created a new branch in my source control (Kiln) called MyApp_iOS5. As I fix bugs in my main branch, I merge those fixes into my iOS5 branch. As the SDK 5 matures and APIs are changed, I make those changes in my iOS5 branch to get it to work in that SDK. This way you can maintain a current release of your app, and make the changes necessary for the new SDK without wasting effort.

Comment: Makes sense...I realized that all my compilation errors rose when I switched from the 5.0 simulator to the 4.3 one. Same code exactly. That's quite frustrating and I hope that it will compile once the SDK 5 matures, otherwise I'll be pretty lost...;)

Comment: With major SDK updates (4.x to 5.x, 5.x to 6.x) it's very likely you'll have to change your code. That is just the way of working with an API, and kind of the purpose behind a major revision bump. Between minor revisions (4.1 to 4.2) it's a lot less likely that you'll have to make code changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. To clean anything related to location services, go to settings and reset location warnings.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue - it would stop fine on iOS 6 devices, but on devices running 5.1, stopUpdatingLocation didn't work & the location services indicator would remain in the status bar. Bizarrely, we fixed it with -

```
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
[locationManager stopUpdatingHeading];
[locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

...even though we started it using only [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

It might have been a bug in iOS - I can't see anything wrong with our code prior to this fix.